# float image inside a div

Tags: html, css

Hi I'm working on a mockup design converting to HTML/CSS.

How can I float the man image inside the third box?
I tried to use the images and have transparent on the upper part so the background images of each column will be equal but when I hover it, the upper part is containing blank/white space which is not good.
See the image letter B

A
[image: A]

B
[image]

```css
.home-sections .left-side .title{
   background: #3666af;
   height: 130px;
   padding: 0 30px;
   position: relative;
   z-index: 2;
   overflow: hidden;
  }
  .home-sections .left-side .title h2{
   margin: 0;
   line-height: 130px;
  }
  .home-sections .left-side .title span{
   font-size: 18px;
   color: #f8f8f8;
   padding-left: 10px;
  }


  .home-sections .left-side .item .team-title{
   font-size: 25px;
   font-weight: 400;
   font-family: ralewaylight;
   margin-top:0;
   padding-bottom: 10px;
  }
  .home-sections .left-side .item .team-title span{
   display: block;
   font-size: 50px;
   font-weight: 900;
   font-family: 'ralewayextrabold';
   position: relative;
   top: -5px;
  }
  .home-sections .left-side .item .team-position{
   font-size: 19px;
  }
  .home-sections .left-side .item .info{
   max-width: 75%;
   margin: 0 auto;
   color: #b1b1b1;
   font-size: 1.1em;
   padding: 34px 0 15px 0;
   position: relative;
  }
  .home-sections .left-side .item .info:before{
   content: '';
   position: absolute;
   top:0;
   left: 50%;
   width: 20%;
   margin-left: -10%;
   height: 4px;
   background:#8ead42;
  }
  .home-sections .left-side .item .info .description p:last-child{
   margin-bottom: 0;
  }
  .home-sections .left-side .item .social-icons{
   margin: 0;
  }
  .home-sections .left-side .item .social-icons li{
   list-style: none;
   display: inline-block;
   font-size: 20px;
   padding: 0 5px;
  }
  .home-sections .left-side .item .social-icons li a{
   color: #797979;
   font-size: 20px;
   -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
      -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease;
    -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease;
     -o-transition: all 0.3s ease;
     transition: all 0.3s ease;
  }
  .home-sections .left-side .item .social-icons li a:hover{
   color: #fff;
  }

  .home-sections .home-sections-item{
   position: relative;
   text-align: center;

  }
  .home-sections .home-sections-head{
   position: relative;
  }
  .home-sections .home-sections-head > img{
   width: 100%;
  }
  .home-sections .home-sections-head:after{
   content: '';
   position: absolute;
   top: 0;
   left:0;
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
   /*background: #dedede;
   opacity: 0.2;*/
   -webkit-transition: all .25s ease;
      -moz-transition: all .25s ease;
    -ms-transition: all .25s ease;
     -o-transition: all .25s ease;
     transition: all .25s ease;
  }
  .home-sections-item .home-sections-content{
   background: #fafafa;
   padding: 30px;
   border: 1px solid #ebebeb;
   border-top: none;
   box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 8px -4px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  }

  .home-sections-item .home-sections-content .title{
   font-size: 25px;
   color: #474747;
   font-weight: 500;
   font-family: 'ralewaymedium';
   margin-top: 0;
   margin-bottom: 10px;

  }

  .home-sections-item .home-sections-content .subtitle{
   text-transform: uppercase;
   color: #adadad;
   font-size: 16px;
   position: relative;
   margin: 0;
   padding-top: 15px;
  }
  .home-sections-item .home-sections-content .subtitle:after{
   content: '';
   position: absolute;
   top:0;
   left: 50%;
   width: 60px;
   height: 2px;
   background: #8ead42;  
   margin-left: -30px;

  }

  .home-sections-button{
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
   list-style: none;
   position: absolute;
   bottom: 10px;
   left: 0;
   width: 100%;
   z-index: 1;
   opacity: 0;

   -webkit-transition: all .75s ease;
      -moz-transition: all .75s ease;
    -ms-transition: all .75s ease;
     -o-transition: all .75s ease;
     transition: all .75s ease;

  }

  .home-sections-button li{
   display: inline-block;
   margin-right: 10px;

  }

  .home-sections-button li:last-child{
   margin-right: 0;
  }
  .home-sections-button li a{
   display: block;
   color: #8ead42;
   text-align: center;
  }
  .home-sections-button li a i{
   width: 50px;
   height: 50px;
   border-radius: 50%;
   border:1px solid #8ead42;
   text-align: center;
   line-height: 50px;
   font-size: 20px;
   box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px -1px rgba(0,0,0,0.2), inset 1px 1px 3px -1px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
   text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);


  }

  .home-sections-button li a:hover i,.home-sections-button li a:focus i{
   background: #8ead42;
   box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px -1px rgba(0,0,0,0), inset 1px 1px 3px -1px rgba(0,0,0,0);
   text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0);
   color: #fff;
  }

  .home-sections-item:hover .home-sections-head:after,.home-sections-item:focus .home-sections-head:after{
   opacity: 0.5;
   background:#000;
  }
  .home-sections-item:hover .home-sections-button,.home-sections-item:focus .home-sections-button{
   bottom: 80px;
   opacity: 1;
   -webkit-transition: all .25s ease, color 0.75s ease;
      -moz-transition: all .25s ease, color 0.75s ease;
    -ms-transition: all .25s ease, color 0.75s ease;
     -o-transition: all .25s ease, color 0.75s ease;
     transition: all .25s ease, color 0.75s ease; 
  }

  .row > :first-child,.section > :first-child, div[class^='col-'] > :first-child{
   margin-top: 0 !important;
  }
  .row > :last-child,.section > :last-child, div[class^='col-'] > :last-child{
   margin-bottom: 0 !important;
  }
```

```html
 <div class="row mb-xlarge">
  <div class="home-sections"> 
    <div class="col-md-4">
     <div class="home-sections-item">
      <div class="home-sections-head">
       <img src="images/gallery/thumbs/thumb_01.png" alt="">
       <ul class="home-sections-button">
        <li><a href="#"><img src="images/icon-hover.png"></a></li>
       </ul>
      </div>

      <div class="home-sections-content">
       <h3 class="title">Nos projets domiciliaire</h3>
       <h4 class="subtitle">PLUS DE DÉTAILS </h4>
      </div> 
     </div>
    </div>
      
    <div class="col-md-4">
     <div class="home-sections-item">
      <div class="home-sections-head">
       <img src="images/gallery/thumbs/thumb_02.png" alt="">
        <ul class="home-sections-button">
         <li><a href="#"><img src="images/icon-hover.png"></a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>

      <div class="home-sections-content">
       <h3 class="title">Modèles disponible</h3>
       <h4 class="subtitle">VOIR LES MODÈLES</h4>
      </div>
         
     </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-4">
     <div class="home-sections-item">
      <div class="home-sections-head">
       <img src="images/gallery/thumbs/thumb_03.png" alt="">
       <ul class="home-sections-button">
        <li><a href="#"><img src="images/icon-hover.png"></a></li>
       </ul>
      </div>

      <div class="home-sections-content">
       <h3 class="title">Qualité de construction</h3>
       <h4 class="subtitle">lIRE PLUS </h4>
      </div>
         
     </div>
    </div>   
  </div>   
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make your image `display: block`

```
.home-sections-head img{
    display: block;
}
```

**[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/shanidkv/91qqLdby/)**

Answer (score 0):

**Vertical-align: top** solves the problem you depicted in B part.

You don't have to float the image itself since the images itself and its description are inside **.col-mid-4**. Adding property value of inline-block to .cols-mid-4 will have the image look as if it's floated and also have the look you want in terms of arranging the image and its description.

Add the block of CSS code below to you yours

```
.col-md-4 {
      display: inline-block;
      vertical-align: top; /* solves the problem in B part */
      margin: 0 20px 20px 0; /* Adjust as needed */
      }
```

**Note:** To achieve a uniform look, add **width**, **height**, and **overflow** with the property value of **hidden**.

```css
.col-md-4 {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  margin: 0 20px 20px 0; /* Adjust as needed */
  }



.home-sections .left-side .title{
   background: #3666af;
   height: 130px;
   padding: 0 30px;
   position: relative;
   z-index: 2;
   overflow: hidden;
  }
  .home-sections .left-side .title h2{
   margin: 0;
   line-height: 130px;
  }
  .home-sections .left-side .title span{
   font-size: 18px;
   color: #f8f8f8;
   padding-left: 10px;
  }


  .home-sections .left-side .item .team-title{
   font-size: 25px;
   font-weight: 400;
   font-family: ralewaylight;
   margin-top:0;
   padding-bottom: 10px;
  }
  .home-sections .left-side .item .team-title span{
   display: block;
   font-size: 50px;
   font-weight: 900;
   font-family: 'ralewayextrabold';
   position: relative;
   top: -5px;
  }
  .home-sections .left-side .item .team-position{
   font-size: 19px;
  }
  .home-sections .left-side .item .info{
   max-width: 75%;
   margin: 0 auto;
   color: #b1b1b1;
   font-size: 1.1em;
   padding: 34px 0 15px 0;
   position: relative;
  }
  .home-sections .left-side .item .info:before{
   content: '';
   position: absolute;
   top:0;
   left: 50%;
   width: 20%;
   margin-left: -10%;
   height: 4px;
   background:#8ead42;
  }
  .home-sections .left-side .item .info .description p:last-child{
   margin-bottom: 0;
  }
  .home-sections .left-side .item .social-icons{
   margin: 0;
  }
  .home-sections .left-side .item .social-icons li{
   list-style: none;
   display: inline-block;
   font-size: 20px;
   padding: 0 5px;
  }
  .home-sections .left-side .item .social-icons li a{
   color: #797979;
   font-size: 20px;
   -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
      -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease;
    -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease;
     -o-transition: all 0.3s ease;
     transition: all 0.3s ease;
  }
  .home-sections .left-side .item .social-icons li a:hover{
   color: #fff;
  }

  .home-sections .home-sections-item{
   position: relative;
   text-align: center;

  }
  .home-sections .home-sections-head{
   position: relative;
  }
  .home-sections .home-sections-head > img{
   width: 100%;
  }
  .home-sections .home-sections-head:after{
   content: '';
   position: absolute;
   top: 0;
   left:0;
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
   /*background: #dedede;
   opacity: 0.2;*/
   -webkit-transition: all .25s ease;
      -moz-transition: all .25s ease;
    -ms-transition: all .25s ease;
     -o-transition: all .25s ease;
     transition: all .25s ease;
  }
  .home-sections-item .home-sections-content{
   background: #fafafa;
   padding: 30px;
   border: 1px solid #ebebeb;
   border-top: none;
   box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 8px -4px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  }

  .home-sections-item .home-sections-content .title{
   font-size: 25px;
   color: #474747;
   font-weight: 500;
   font-family: 'ralewaymedium';
   margin-top: 0;
   margin-bottom: 10px;

  }

  .home-sections-item .home-sections-content .subtitle{
   text-transform: uppercase;
   color: #adadad;
   font-size: 16px;
   position: relative;
   margin: 0;
   padding-top: 15px;
  }
  .home-sections-item .home-sections-content .subtitle:after{
   content: '';
   position: absolute;
   top:0;
   left: 50%;
   width: 60px;
   height: 2px;
   background: #8ead42;  
   margin-left: -30px;

  }

  .home-sections-button{
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
   list-style: none;
   position: absolute;
   bottom: 10px;
   left: 0;
   width: 100%;
   z-index: 1;
   opacity: 0;

   -webkit-transition: all .75s ease;
      -moz-transition: all .75s ease;
    -ms-transition: all .75s ease;
     -o-transition: all .75s ease;
     transition: all .75s ease;

  }

  .home-sections-button li{
   display: inline-block;
   margin-right: 10px;

  }

  .home-sections-button li:last-child{
   margin-right: 0;
  }
  .home-sections-button li a{
   display: block;
   color: #8ead42;
   text-align: center;
  }
  .home-sections-button li a i{
   width: 50px;
   height: 50px;
   border-radius: 50%;
   border:1px solid #8ead42;
   text-align: center;
   line-height: 50px;
   font-size: 20px;
   box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px -1px rgba(0,0,0,0.2), inset 1px 1px 3px -1px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
   text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);


  }

  .home-sections-button li a:hover i,.home-sections-button li a:focus i{
   background: #8ead42;
   box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px -1px rgba(0,0,0,0), inset 1px 1px 3px -1px rgba(0,0,0,0);
   text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0);
   color: #fff;
  }

  .home-sections-item:hover .home-sections-head:after,.home-sections-item:focus .home-sections-head:after{
   opacity: 0.5;
   background:#000;
  }
  .home-sections-item:hover .home-sections-button,.home-sections-item:focus .home-sections-button{
   bottom: 80px;
   opacity: 1;
   -webkit-transition: all .25s ease, color 0.75s ease;
      -moz-transition: all .25s ease, color 0.75s ease;
    -ms-transition: all .25s ease, color 0.75s ease;
     -o-transition: all .25s ease, color 0.75s ease;
     transition: all .25s ease, color 0.75s ease; 
  }

  .row > :first-child,.section > :first-child, div[class^='col-'] > :first-child{
   margin-top: 0 !important;
  }
  .row > :last-child,.section > :last-child, div[class^='col-'] > :last-child{
   margin-bottom: 0 !important;
  }
```

```html
<div class="row mb-xlarge">
  <div class="home-sections"> 
    <div class="col-md-4">
     <div class="home-sections-item">
      <div class="home-sections-head">
       <img src="images/gallery/thumbs/thumb_01.png" alt="">
       <ul class="home-sections-button">
        <li><a href="#"><img src="images/icon-hover.png"></a></li>
       </ul>
      </div>

      <div class="home-sections-content">
       <h3 class="title">Nos projets domiciliaire</h3>
       <h4 class="subtitle">PLUS DE DÉTAILS </h4>
      </div> 
     </div>
    </div>
      
    <div class="col-md-4">
     <div class="home-sections-item">
      <div class="home-sections-head">
       <img src="images/gallery/thumbs/thumb_02.png" alt="">
        <ul class="home-sections-button">
         <li><a href="#"><img src="images/icon-hover.png"></a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>

      <div class="home-sections-content">
       <h3 class="title">Modèles disponible</h3>
       <h4 class="subtitle">VOIR LES MODÈLES</h4>
      </div>
         
     </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-4">
     <div class="home-sections-item">
      <div class="home-sections-head">
       <img src="images/gallery/thumbs/thumb_03.png" alt="">
       <ul class="home-sections-button">
        <li><a href="#"><img src="images/icon-hover.png"></a></li>
       </ul>
      </div>

      <div class="home-sections-content">
       <h3 class="title">Qualité de construction</h3>
       <h4 class="subtitle">lIRE PLUS </h4>
      </div>
         
     </div>
    </div>   
  </div>   
</div>
```